# дочерний обьект не перемещается за родительским

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Делаю обьект GameObect.transform.parent = Player.transform;
Раньше все работало прекрасно, обьект прикреплялся к Плееру по нажатию кнопки, по нажатию этой же кнопки бросался на землю (проект 2D), но после того, как именилась система перемещения (стала по координатам), обьект становился дочерним, помещался на место игрока и не двигался за ним, приравнял положение обьекта к положению игрока стало работать, но вопрос теперь такой, я не могу бросить обьект, если делаю переменную принажатии которой обьекту даются координаты игрока, он продолжает двигаться за ним

```
 void pressedF()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        if (entered)
        {
            if (EquipBoxPl.GetComponent<equipboxplace>().eqbox == true)
            {
                poss = true;
                Debug.Log("PRESSED");
                boxinarm = true;
                pas = false;
                gameObject.transform.parent = Player.transform;
                gameObject.transform.position = _playerPos + center;
            }
        }
    }
    if (boxinarm)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            gameObject.transform.parent = null;
                gameObject.transform.position = _playerPos;
            if (!pas)
            {
                pas = true;
            }
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
            boxinarm = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
GameObject.transform.parent = Player.transform
```

Убрать из дочерних

```
GameObject.transform.parent = null
```